# Kernel crash after repeated use of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, kernel, crash, version-12.1

I am trying to solve the Einstein-Klein-Gordon system (equations below) for different piecewise potentials but the kernel keeps crashing after repeated use of NDSolve. 
Apparently, everything works fine at first, meaning that I don't get any relevant warning and I obtain solutions with the features I expect. However, after some time (not always the same period of time) the kernel crashes without any previous warning. 
I tried to keep track of the memory used at each step, but it never reaches a large value, so it doesn't seem to me that it is a memory related crash.

Let me show you a short code that reproduces the crash:

```
(*POTENTIAL & PARAMETERS:*)

$HistoryLength = 0; ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
rmax0 = 80; rmin = 1/10^17; cut = 1/10; pcmax = 89/200; 

Vpot[r] = Piecewise[{{p[r]^2/(4*Pi), p[r] < 217/500},
                     {-(87/250) + (4*p[r])/5 + (87*(-1827 + 4400*p[r]))/(160000*Pi),  p[r] >= 109/250},
                     {(86031603 + 640*Pi*(217 - 500*p[r])^2 - 405876800*p[r] + 500350000*p[r]^2 - 50000000*p[r]^3)/(800000*Pi), True}}]; 

Upot[r] = Piecewise[{{1, p[r] <= 217/500},
                     {(957 + 320*Pi)/(200*p[r]), p[r] >= 109/250}, 
                     {10007/4 + Pi*(800 - 1736/(5*p[r])) - 253673/(250*p[r]) - 375*p[r], True}}]; 

(*INITIAL CONDITIONS:*)

upp0ff[pc_, w_] := -(52983/10000) + (319*pc)/25 + (8*Pi*(-87 + 200*pc))/375 + (4*pc^2*w^2)/3
vpp0ff[pc_, w_] := 52983/10000 - (319*pc)/25 + (8*Pi*(87 - 200*pc))/375 + (8*pc^2*w^2)/3
ppp0ff[pc_, w_] := 319/200 + 8*Pi/15 - (pc*w^2)/3


(*FUNCTION:*)

ClearAll[bosonstar]; 
bosonstar[pc_?NumericQ, initw_?NumericQ] := {
   ClearAll[flagroots, initf0, sol, p, u, v]; 
   initf0 = Round[N[IntegerPart[initw*10^3]/10^3], 10^(-3)]; 
   dif = Round[N[IntegerPart[(initw/10)*10^2]/10^2], 10^(-2)]; 

   sol[w_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{u'[r] == (1 - E^u[r])/r + 2*r*(w^2*E^(u[r] - v[r])*p[r]^2 + p'[r]^2 + 4*Pi*E^u[r]*Vpot[r]), 
                       v'[r] == (-1 + E^u[r])/r + 2*r*(w^2*E^(u[r] - v[r])*p[r]^2 + p'[r]^2 - 4*Pi*E^u[r]*Vpot[r]), 
                       p''[r] == ((u'[r] - v'[r])/2 - 2/r)*p'[r] + E^u[r]*(Upot[r] - w^2/E^v[r])*p[r], 

                       u[rmin] == (1/2)*upp0ff[pc, w]*rmin^2, 
                       p[rmin] == pc + (1/2)*ppp0ff[pc, w]*rmin^2, 
                       p'[rmin] == ppp0ff[pc, w]*rmin, 
                       v[rmin] == (1/2)*vpp0ff[pc, w]*rmin^2, 

                       WhenEvent[p[r] == 0 && r < (rmax0*cut+1), {rfin=r, flagroots = 1, "StopIntegration"}],
                       WhenEvent[Abs[p[r]] > (1/3) pc, {flagroots = 0, "StopIntegration"}], 
                       WhenEvent[p[r] > (pc + 0.01), {flagroots = 0, "StopIntegration"}]}, 

                      {p, u, v}, {r, rmin, rmax0}, WorkingPrecision -> wprecision]; 

   sol[initf0]; 
   If[flagroots == 1, {initdo = 1, dif = -dif}, initdo = 0]; 

   Do[{

       While[flagroots != (1 + (-1)^(i))/2,
             {flagroots = 0,
              initf0 = initf0 + dif,
              sol[initf0]}],

       If[rfin >= rmax0 cut, Break[]],

       dif = (Abs[dif]/10) (-1)^(i + 1)

      }, {i, initdo, 31, 1}]

}
```

At first, the function `bosonstar` can be used to find solutions without any apparent problem. But if it is run several times, it eventually leads to a crash. For instance:

```
Do[{i = i + 1, 
    wprecision = 15,
    bosonstar[pcmax, 3],
    If[rfin < rmax0 cut, {wprecision = wprecision + 2, rmin = 10^-wprecision, bosonstar[pcmax, 3]}],
    Print[i]}, 
   {i, 0, 1000}]
```

This leads to a crash when I run it, although not always at the same step.

I would greatly appreciate any comment, advice or hint! Thanks!!

NOTE: If I try with a simple parabolic potential

```
Vpot[r] = p[r]^2/(4*Pi)
Upot[r] = 1
```

with the corresponding initial conditions

```
upp0ff[pc_, w_] := 4/3 pc^2 (1 + w^2)
vpp0ff[pc_, w_] := 4/3 pc^2 (-1 + 2 w^2)
ppp0ff[pc_, w_] := 1/3 (pc - pc w^2)
```

it doesn't seem to crash, so maybe the problem has to do with the way I define and/or use the piecewise potential.

Comment: Do you have access to an older version, e.g. 12.0? Does the same code cause crashes there as well?

Comment: I first tried the code on version 11.3 and it did also crash

Comment: Maybe it is using too much memory for the available RAM?

Comment: I kept track of the memory usage and I didn't impose any constraint on it at all but it still crashes

Comment: I tried it on my desktop Mac with 32Gb of Ram (macOS 10.15.4 and WL 12.1), and it crashes after 29 iterations. Looks like a bug to me - I suggest you report it to Wolfram Research, since you have a reproducible bug here.

Comment: Also (not sure if it's related) but `NDSolve` prints this error message during the execution (and after 3 messages everything else is suspended): `NDSolve::ndsz: At r == 0.44739755641711368331992254968485336411`17., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Concerning the error message, I think it is not related at all (actually I expect the solution to blow up at some point). But just in case, I just edited the function so that it doesn't produce any error message at all and it still crashes.

Comment: Change the definitions to `Vpot[r_] =…,Upot[r_] =…  `. With this modification your code runs without crash (MathematicA v12 Windows)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it but the crash still persists...

Comment: Please put a bit more effort in creating a [minimal working example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871).