# Piecewise function and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, piecewise, kernel, crash

I'm trying to solve a system of differenial equations involving a piecewise function with NDSolve. I tried to define this function using `Piecewise` but the kernel keeps crashing. 
I also tried to express the function in terms of `UnitStep` and `HeavisideTheta`by means of `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` but the crash still takes place.
(More details on a particular system of equations and its numerical implementation can be found here [Kernel crash after repeated use of NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218704/kernel-crash-after-repeated-use-of-ndsolve))

Do you know if there is any other alternative or workaround that I could use in order to avoid this annoying crash?

Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm not really sure I understand what you say but in principle Vpot and Upot are constructed in a way that enusures continuity and differentiability. Plus, it is very important to keep the same expression (parabolic in this case) in the first interval.

Comment: Gotta include the code, otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Hey! To see the code just click on the link

Comment: So this is the same exact problem as in the previous one? Then you should not post a new question just to bump it up the queue.

Comment: Well the previous problem is a particular one for a specific set of equations. Here I am just asking a general question for any general system of differential equations, since I found the same crash happening in different cases (this is also why I didn't include any concrete piece of code). I just linked the previous question to provide an example and give some context.

Comment: Reading your previous question, even your specific problem did not have an immediate solution. Furthermore, people could not clearly pinpoint the origin of the crash, **even with the code in hand**. I am not sure how you can expect a general solution from it. If Voting to close as duplicate of your previous question.